# Diverse Kubernetes and Vagrant problems

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, kubernetes

I am using WmWare Workstation running a Linux vm which runs the vagrant and kubernetes environment.

I have a problem using kubernetes with vagrant. Every time if I shutdown the kubernetes cluster with the kube-down.sh tool and restart with kube-up.sh, I cannot connect to the minions anymore! I think it has something to do with the IP binding. Does somebody know what to do?

The other problem is if I try to install the guestbook example I cannot download the redis image. The pods are always stays in PENDING state. Is there a way to download the image manually and add it as a file?

Thank you in advance.

Regards
:)

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot connect to the minions"? How are you trying to connect to them?

Answer (score 1):

Each run of kube-up.sh is intended to generate a new cluster. As such, it will create new credentials for the cluster and any existing nodes are not expected to continue to work with the new master components.

Answer (score 1):

With a slow network it will take a while to set up everything behind the scenes; for me it took about 1h before I saw every pod in a running state:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
guestbook-7ihd2      1/1       Running   0          2h
guestbook-8fjs3      1/1       Running   0          2h
guestbook-fifmm      1/1       Running   0          2h
redis-master-ivebc   1/1       Running   0          3h
redis-slave-6qxga    1/1       Running   0          2h
redis-slave-r8bk4    1/1       Running   0          2h
```

But in the end it worked!